# How to draw random shapes in python?

Tags: python, shapes

I want to draw random shapes in random colors in an image using python. Is there any module which exists in python to draw random shapes like polygons of different sizes and shapes and mixed together to form a new shape etc

Thanks a lot

Comment: well TkInter does stuff like that: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/106935/drawing-a-moving-circle-with-python-tkinter-good-gui-tutorial

Comment: Define what are the random attributes of a shape representable by numbers (number of corners, x-position, y-position, width, height,…), then get all these random numbers and then call a method drawing a shape using these arguments.

Comment: You could tweak the script found in this question: http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/pygame-and-drawing-random-shapes-643278.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being unsure of what you are trying to accomplish, the following code is a simple example of how to generate random shapes and display them in a window. It create a `tkinter` root object, sets up a `Canvas` for display, and randomly creates and shows polygons for each second the program is run.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *

class Application(Canvas):

    X_OFFSET = 40
    Y_OFFSET = 40
    FILL = 'blue'
    LINE = 'black'

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        root = Tk()
        surface = cls(root)
        surface.grid()
        surface.after_idle(surface.draw_shape)
        root.mainloop()

    def draw_shape(self):
        x = randrange(int(self['width']) - self.X_OFFSET)
        y = randrange(int(self['height']) - self.Y_OFFSET)
        points = [(x + randrange(self.X_OFFSET), y + randrange(self.Y_OFFSET))
                  for point in range(randint(3, 10))]
        self.create_polygon(points, fill=self.FILL, outline=self.LINE)
        self.after(1000, self.draw_shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

For creating/modifying an image, [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) would work.

Comment: +1: it sounds like the questioner is probably starting with an image, like a jpg, etc, in which case PIL is the right choice.

Answer (score 1):

[Cairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) might be useful for cross platform GUI, or [SVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/) if you just want it in a browser.